# Typo3 how to add target=_blank parameter in base meta tag

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, tsconfig

I am trying to add **target="_blank"** parameter to the <*base*> Tag in the header, when certain parameters are met.

Currently the base tag is filled with the url give in config.baseUrl:

```
<base href="http://yourdomain.com/">
```

I've gone through the reference and tried different settings (meta, pages.headerData, ..) but I was not able to manipulate the <*base*> tag within the header.

what I want to achieve is this:

```
<base href="http://yourdomain.com/" target="_blank">
```

---

what I got so far is to remove the baseUrl completely and set <*base*> manually:

```
page.headerData.1 = TEXT
page.headerData.1.value < config.baseURL
page.headerData.1.wrap = <base href="|" target="_blank">
config.baseURL >
```

Still i have 2 problems with this: Typo3 (in my case 4.5) adds a CSS link before my  tag - which results in a file not found message when I open any sub-path on the website.
when opening: http://yourdomain.com/path/subpath

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 4.5 CMS">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3temp/stylesheet_xxx.css?xxx" media="all">
    <base href="http://yourdomain.com/" target="_blank">
    <title>Some title</title>
```

chrome says:

```
/path/subpath/stylesheet_xxx.css?xxx    GET 404
```

(where it should find the file in /stylesheet_xxx.css?xxx ..)

the other problem is, that when doing a HMENU with special=rootline

```
logo = HMENU
logo {
   special = rootline
   special.range = 0|0
}
```

the href to the startpage will always be blank, after I unset config.baseUrl.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

/edit: adding a second <*base*> tag in header would work, but the validator doesn't like two base tags :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this constants help you?

```
 # default target for links:
 PAGE_TARGET = _blank
 # target for links in sitemap:
 content.pageFrameObj = _blank
```

From here:
http://www.pi-phi.de/25.html

Comment: This works only (for most of) the typo3 generated links. 

I have also set:

    `config.extTarget = _blank
    config.intTarget = _blank`

it seems links that have explicit set `class="internal-link"` are not modified by this setting - so they are still opening in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

On the first issue (they are related, I know):

I wouldn't add the config setting to page.headerData.1.value, rather use a constant:

```
mydomain = www.mydomain.com
```

then

```
config.baseURL > 
page.headerData.1 = TEXT
page.headerData.1.value < {$mydomain}
page.headerData.1.wrap = <base href="http://|" target="_blank">
```

About the routing issue: is that really so? According to your code, it should look in www.mydomain.com/typo3temp.

In the [documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#baseurl), it says that the baseURL should have an end slash. But in all my sites, I use it without, and it works fine. Give it a try without the end slash.

On the second issue

```
logo = HMENU
logo {
   special = rootline
   special.range = 0|0
}
```

Is this only a "home" link? Then consider adding it with a typolink to the home page's pid instead or even totally by hand, as it will likely never change (`href="\"`).

PS: base tag is a bit out of fashion, but you know that already. I used to use it mostly because of IE 8 issues, and now, well, I'm used to it. Also, for TYPO3, the use of "absRefPrefix" has been recommended. I'm just noting this here academically.

Comment: yes. you are right, baseUrl and also base-Tag ends with /. i'll update that in the question above. 
I don't get that part about the routing issue? If the base-tag is done by typo3 it's positioned before the first CSS include. If I put the base tag by hand, it's inserted after that and Chrome says it cannot find the file under that path - as it's a relative path from the current position, instead of the root directory.
On the second one, the link does not always go to the root page - but instead it points to different pages within the rootline - again when parameters are met.

Comment: I am looking into absRefPrefix right now. I really hope i'll not run into more difficulties using this :)
If anyone does have more ideas - I'll be happy to try them out as well.